# How do debug two scripts( one POSTs varaibles to another)?

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am building a website currently I want to debug the log in script.
For the task I am using Eclipse with the PHP Development Tools plug-in, XDebug.

I understand how to start a debugging session, but I am stuck because I have two files for the task, one is index.php as you can imagine that is the front end, including form that using POST executes script login.php.

My problem is that whenever I start a session to debug index.php and post the variables eclipse does not execute login.php. 
Also whenever I start a session to debug login.php I start with no variables POSTed.

NOTE: That I am debugging scripts as a 'Web page', when debugging as 'PHP script' I could only see the source code thus I could not enter user, and password.

How can I either include both( or even ALL) files in debugging session, or can I start debugging session with dummy POSTs??

Either way will work for me, or other solution if it fits better I am still new to eclipse.

UPDATE: I was wrong when I start session for index.php login.php IS executed I just don't get so see any variables in the variable view.

[image: Image of Project and Debug settings]

Comment: So you can activate the variable view: `Window -> Show View -> Debug`. Can you please take screenshots of your project structure and debug settings and provide them here.

Comment: OK I posted the Screenshot

Comment: I meaned screenshots of your project structure and debug settings -- not the screenshot of the debug view.